# Sherlock Action bar color change

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, background-color

Just want to change Action bar color right now I am using  `Theme.Sherlock.Light.Dark_Action Bar`
need to change color should support api 10 and above

Comment: what have you dont so far? also post your style.xml

Comment: <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#ff000000</item>
        <item name="background">#ff000000</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the following code and it works

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00853c")));
```

hope it will work for you ..

Comment: i am using sherlock action bar

Comment: hey you can go through this link and customize your sherlock action bar as you want  http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: need to apply same action bar color for menu item..reply

Comment: check out  "Popup color" attribute on same link for changing menu, submenu background  .... you have to keep same color for action bar and Popup color attributes

Comment: i have used this code onlygetSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00853c")));

Comment: how to change height and width of menu option used this link and generated action bad jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator

Answer (score 1):

You can add drawable to Actionbar..

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header_drawable_xml));
```

Here is the header_drawable_xml

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="YOUR COLOR" >>YOUR COLOR android:endColor="YOUR COLOR" >> android:angle="270.0" />
     <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```